# new to Apache Cordova: build failed

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to build an Adroid app with javascript... using Apache Cordova. I have followed the instructions and installed the required components but it doesn't work! I get this when I enter build:

C:\Users\qiova\cordova\hello>cordova build
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\qiova\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\qiova\cordova\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 69
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 30.0.3.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\qiova\cordova\hello\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\qiova\cordova\hello\platforms\android\build.gradle

I am trying to build an Adroid app with javascript... using Apache Cordova. I have followed the instructions and installed the required components but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You can download an android sdk in android studio. Just go to settings preferences and search for sdk, there you can add build tools for version 30.0.3. There you can also see what the path is for the sdk. You should add that path to your environment variables (~/.zshrc)
`ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=PATH/TO/SDK`
and add the thools to your path:
`PATH=ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$PATH`
You should also add the folder that contains you platform tools to your path. You can download those here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

If you are still getting the error, you can explicitly point to your build tools as well, by adding them to you environment variables too, with: PATH=${PATH}:path/to/build/tools (they are inside your sdk, platform tools should be there too)
Let me know if you still experience errors.

Comment: I added the every possible path to the version I have... 30.0.2 ... it doesn't work!

Comment: What is your output now? it shouldn't say ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined  anymore

Comment: I tried different paths. also the one that is set in Android Studio. no joy!

Comment: C:\Users\qiova\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: oh, you're on windows, that might be a bit different. Do you get that path if you echo ANDROID_SDK_ROOT in a console?

Comment: I believe on windows, you have to go to your system variables and add it there.

Comment: I have fixed it!!! the problem was my version of Build Tools was too recent! I installed the required version and managed to build my very first Android App!! thank you for your help

Comment: Congratulations, nicely done!